# Extracting data Frame from XML file using Beautiful soup

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I was trying to convert the xml table into data frame using Beautiful Soup .

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd
source = urllib.request.urlopen("http://reports.ieso.ca/public/GenOutputCapability/PUB_GenOutputCapability.xml").read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'xml')

GName = soup.find_all('GeneratorName')
Ftype = soup.find_all('FuelType')
Hour = soup.find_all('Hour')
Mwatt = soup.find_all('EnergyMW')

data = []
for i in range(0,len(GName)):
   rows = [GName[i].get_text(),Ftype[i].get_text(),
           Hour [i].get_text(),Mwatt[i].get_text()
           ]
   data.append(rows)
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns = ['Generator Name','Fuel Type',
                                  'Hour','Energy MW'],
                                   dtype = int)
display(df)
```

```
    Generator Name  Fuel Type   Hour    Energy MW
0   BRUCEA-G1   NUCLEAR     1   777
1   BRUCEA-G2   NUCLEAR     2   777
2   BRUCEA-G3   NUCLEAR     3   777
3   BRUCEA-G4   NUCLEAR     4   778
4   BRUCEB-G5   NUCLEAR     5   780
...     ...     ...     ...     ...
175     STONE MILLS SF  SOLAR   8   0
176     WINDSOR AIRPORT SF  SOLAR   9   0
177     ATIKOKAN-G1     BIOFUEL     10  0
178     CALSTOCKGS  BIOFUEL     11  0
179     TBAYBOWATER CTS     BIOFUEL     12  0

180 rows × 4 columns
```

The final data frame gives only the Energy MW  of index 0 only . It should be for all 180 stations  .
I am stuck up .
Thanks

Comment: what's your expected output ? show output for one row?

Comment: Present dataframe only shows MW of all Hours of BRUCEA-G1( Generator Name) only . where as it should give for all Generator .

Comment: check below answer then

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty gnarly xml you have there and it takes some efforts to convert to a table which looks like the one on the page:

```
#first, some required imports
import itertools
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://reports.ieso.ca/public/GenOutputCapability/PUB_GenOutputCapability.xml'

req = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(req.text,'lxml')

gens = soup.select('Generator')
#We have to get the names of the 180 generators and double it to have 2 rows each:
gen_names = [gen.select_one('generatorname').text for gen in gens]
gen_names = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(x, 2) for x in gen_names))

# we also need to create a list 180 Capability and Output pairs and flatten it to 360:
vars = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(x, 180) for x in [["Capability","Output"]]))
vars = list(itertools.chain(*vars))

#all that in order to create a MultiIndex dataframe:
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([gen_names,vars], names=["Generator", "Hours"])

#create column names equal to the hours - note that, depending on the time of day the data is downloaded there could be more or less columns
cols = list(range(1,20))

#now collect the data; there may be shorter ways to do that, but for I used a longer method, for easier readability
data = []
for gen in gens:
    row = []
    row.append([g.text for g in gen.select('Capability  energymw')])
    row.append([g.text for g in gen.select('Output energymw')])
    data.extend(row)
pd.DataFrame(data,index=index,columns=cols)
```

Output (pardon the formatting):

```
                        1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
Generator   Hours                                                                           
BRUCEA-G1   Capability  795     795     795     795     795     795     795     795     795     795     795     795     795     795     795     795     795     795     795
Output  776     775     775     774     775     775     774     774     774     775     776     777     777     775     774     773     773     774     774
BRUCEA-G2   Capability  779     779     779     779     779     779     779     779     779     779     779     779     779     779     779     779     779     779     779
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

One way might be to use the indicated transform document and `etree.XSLT` to apply the transform which generates the table. Select that table, with `pandas` `read_html`, then do a little sprucing on the headers if desired.

```
from lxml import etree
from pandas import read_html as rh

transform = etree.XSLT(etree.parse('http://reports.ieso.ca/docrefs/stylesheet/GenOutputCapability_HTML_t1-4.xsl'))
result_tree = transform(etree.parse('http://reports.ieso.ca/public/GenOutputCapability/PUB_GenOutputCapability.xml'))
df = rh(str(result_tree), match = 'Hours')[0]
df.columns = df.iloc[1, :] 
df = df.iloc[2:, ]
df
```

---

Read about the transform steps here: https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xslt

Comment: `from lxml.html import parse` then `parse(url)` directly. ?

Answer (score 0):

```py
from lxml.html import parse
import pandas as pd


def main(url):
    data = parse(url).find('.//generators')
    allin = []
    for i in data:
        allin.append({
            'GeneratorName': i[0].text,
            'FuelType': i[1].text,
            'Outputs': [x.text for x in i[2].cssselect('EnergyMW')],
            'Capabilities': [x.text for x in i[3].cssselect('EnergyMW')],
            'capacities': [x.text for x in i[4].cssselect('EnergyMW')]
        })
    df = pd.DataFrame(allin)
    print(df)


main('http://reports.ieso.ca/public/GenOutputCapability/PUB_GenOutputCapability.xml')
```

Output:

```
          GeneratorName  ...                                         capacities
0             BRUCEA-G1  ...  [795, 795, 795, 795, 795, 795, 795, 795, 795, ...
1             BRUCEA-G2  ...  [779, 779, 779, 779, 779, 779, 779, 779, 779, ...
2             BRUCEA-G3  ...  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
3             BRUCEA-G4  ...  [760, 760, 760, 760, 760, 760, 760, 760, 760, ...
4             BRUCEB-G5  ...  [817, 817, 817, 817, 817, 817, 817, 817, 817, ...
..                  ...  ...                                                ...
175      STONE MILLS SF  ...  [54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 5...
176  WINDSOR AIRPORT SF  ...  [50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 5...
177         ATIKOKAN-G1  ...  [215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, 215, ...
178          CALSTOCKGS  ...  [38, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
179     TBAYBOWATER CTS  ...  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, ...

[180 rows x 5 columns]
```